# Primefaces push.js Uncaught Error: message length "[message]" is not a number

Tags: javascript, primefaces, atmosphere, server-push

I created a live feed Twitter with PrimeFaces (5.2.13) and Atmosphere (2.3.8) which use the channel "/TwitterFeed/[subject]". I push datas to the client at JSON format.

In the client side, I receive my array of object from the server, but after a moment (or directly, it depends on the context), a JavaScript error block the information's reception.

Here is an extract of my error :

push.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.2.13:1

```
Uncaught Error: message length "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[{"created_at":"Thu Sep 01 09:38:09 +0000 2016","id":771280977675096064,"id_str":"771280977675096064","text":"Pokemon cards and Poster https:\/\/t.co\/imBqGKpMz9 https:\/\/t.co\/Gym0Tw7k3l","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/imBqGKpMz9","expanded_url":"http:\/\/rover.ebay.com\/rover\/1\/711-53200-19255-0\/1?ff3=2&toolid=10044&campid=5337410313&customid=&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466&item=112108972120&pub=5575041009","display_url":"rover.ebay.com\/rover\/1\/711-53?","indices":[25,48]}],"media":[{"id":771280975804399616,"id_str":"771280975804399616","indices":[49,72],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CrQj9gjWgAAVCqG.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CrQj9gjWgAAVCqG.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/Gym0Tw7k3l","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/Gym0Tw7k3l","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/Keumme__Zaalwo\/status\/771280977675096064\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":88,"h":88,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":140,"h":88,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":140,"h":88,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":140,"h":88,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":771280975804399616,"id_str":"771280975804399616","indices":[49,72],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CrQj9gjWgAAVCqG.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CrQj9gjWgAAVCqG.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/Gym0Tw7k3l","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/Gym0Tw7k3l","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/Keumme__Zaalwo\/status\/771280977675096064\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":88,"h":88,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":140,"h":88,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":140,"h":88,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":140,"h":88,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">IFTTT<\/a>","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":3781069215,"id_str":"3781069215","name":"Keumme Zaalwo","screen_name":"Keumme__Zaalwo","location":"New York, USA","description":"fashion,music sport,travel,shopping","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":547,"friends_count":0,"listed_count":457,"created_at":"Sat Sep 26 10:50:41 +0000 2015","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":490965,"lang":"pl","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/647725928592883712\/N_AS5rfS_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/647725928592883712\/N_AS5rfS_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/3781069215\/1443264885","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"},{"created_at":"Thu Sep 01 09:38:08 +0000 2016","id":771280973287882752,"id_str":"771280973287882752","text":"RT @Kimyongur: Assis dans un parc, mon fils de 8 ans me demande la diff�rence entre un putsch et une r�volution. A c�t�, un ado de 16 ans j?","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":
...
" is not a number
```

As you can see there is some � character, instead of accents (é and ô here).
I think the problem might comes from the accents.

The server in continuing to send push objects, but client don't care :)

Client side code :

```
        <framework:blockLevel1
            legend="Twitter Search">
            <framework:textFormItem id="topic" label="Enter an hashtag" />
            <framework:actionButton value="Get Real Time Tweet"
                        id="connect" ajax="true" />
                    <framework:actionButton value="Stop Real Time Tweet" id="stop"
                        ajax="true"  />
            <framework:blockLevel2 legend="Real Time Twitter Search">
                <ul id="result"></ul>
            </framework:blockLevel2>
        </framework:blockLevel1>
        <link
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var list = $('#result');
            function handleMessage(data) {
               console.log(data);
               if(Array.isArray(data)) {
                   data.forEach(function(elem) {
                       var text = '';
                       text += '<a class="user" href="https://twitter.com/' + elem.user.screen_name + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + elem.user.profile_image_url_https + '"/><span class="names"><span class="name">' + elem.user.name + '</span><span class="screen_name">@' + elem.user.screen_name + '</span></span></a>';
                       if(elem.retweeted_status != null) {
                           text += '<span class="retweet_creator"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i>Retweeted from <a href="https://twitter.com/' + elem.retweeted_status.user.screen_name + '" target="_blank">@' + elem.retweeted_status.user.screen_name + '</a></span>';
                       }
                       elem.text = elem.text.replace(/((http|https):\/\/(\w|\.)+\/\w+)/g, function addLinksToHashtags(x) {return '<a href="' + x + '" target="_blank">' + x + '</a>';});
                       elem.text = elem.text.replace(/(@\w+)/g, function addLinksToUsers(x) {return '<a href="https://twitter.com/' + x.replace('@', '') + '" target="_blank">' + x + '</a>';});
                       elem.text = elem.text.replace(/(#\w+)/g, function addLinksToHashtags(x) {return '<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + x.replace('#', '') + '" target="_blank">' + x + '</a>';});
                       text += '<p class="text">' + elem.text + '</p>';
                       text += '<div class="icons">';
                       text += '<div class="icon_wrapper"><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/' + elem.user.screen_name + '/status/' + elem.id_str + '" target="_blank" title="See it on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></div>';
                       text += '<div class="icon_wrapper"><span class="retweet_count"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i>' + elem.retweet_count + '</span></div>';
                       text += '<div class="icon_wrapper"><span class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>' + elem.favorite_count + '</span></div>';
                       text += '</div>';
                       list.prepend('<li class="tweet">' + text + '</li>');
                   });
               }
            }
        </script>

        <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage"
            channel="#{twitterFeed.getChannel()}" autoConnect="false"
            widgetVar='subscriber' />
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                function getKeyCode(ev) {
                    if (window.event) return window.event.keyCode;
                    return ev.keyCode;
                }
                function getElementById(id) {
                    return document.getElementById(id);
                }
                function getElementByIdValue(id) {
                    return document.getElementById(id).value;
                }
                function subscribe() {
                    PF('subscriber').connect('/' + getElementByIdValue('topic_fmkfield'));
                    console.log(document.location.origin + '/xxx-framework-ui-jsf2-showcase/rest/search/' + getElementByIdValue('topic_fmkfield'));
                    var request = { url : document.location.origin + '/xxx-framework-ui-jsf2-showcase/rest/search/' + getElementByIdValue('topic_fmkfield'),
                        trackMessageLength : true
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: request.url,
                        data: request
                    });
                }
                function connect() {
                    if (getElementByIdValue('topic_fmkfield') == '') {
                        alert("Please enter a hashtag");
                    }
                    subscribe();
                    getElementById('connect').value = "Switch transport";
                    return false;
                }
                function stop() {
                    var request = { url : document.location.origin + '/xxx-framework-ui-jsf2-showcase/rest/search/' + getElementByIdValue('topic_fmkfield') + "/stop" }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: request.url
                    });
                }
                getElementById('connect').onclick = function(event) {
                    connect();
                    return false;
                }
                getElementById('stop').onclick = function(event) {
                    stop();
                    return false;
                }
                getElementById('topic_fmkfield').onkeyup = function(event) {
                    var keyc = getKeyCode(event);
                    if (keyc == 13 || keyc == 10) {
                        connect();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                getElementById('topic_fmkfield').focus();
            });
</script>
```

Also, I've got a server side error with special characters such as Chinese or emoji's characters.

```
11:38:31,114 WARN  [org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeInterceptor] (Atmosphere-Shared-31) Cannot decode the response bytes for 4f4e5c03-868d-4b9c-9599-fd68af82b72d. Writing the message as it is: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:816) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeInterceptor$Interceptor.transformPayload(TrackMessageSizeInterceptor.java:145) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.invokeInterceptor(AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.java:81) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.write(AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.java:69) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.write(AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.java:64) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse$Stream.write(AtmosphereResponse.java:1002) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.atmosphere.handler.AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.java:154) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy.onStateChange(PushEndpointHandlerProxy.java:253) [primefaces-5.2.13.jar:5.2.13]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.invokeOnStateChange(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1047) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.prepareInvokeOnStateChange(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1067) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:872) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster$2.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:474) [atmosphere-runtime-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
```

But it not seems to be linked.

Have you already met those problems ?

Thanks.